# How to create foreign key in Laravel 4.2 on column that is string

Tags: mysql, string, laravel, migration

I'm trying to add foreign key on a `string` ccolumn but it only adds index not foreign key constraint. Here's my migration:

```html
public function up()
{
Schema::create('pagemeta', function(Blueprint $table)
{
$table->increments('id')->unsigned();
$table->string('pageId', 255)->nullable()->index();
$table->timestamps();

});
Schema::table('pagemeta', function(Blueprint $table)
{
$table->foreign('pageId')->references('id')->on('pages')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');

});
}
```

In `pages` table column `id` is also varchar type.

It returns the following error:

`SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table 'db.#sql
  -4b4_1abda2' (errno: 150) (SQL: alter table`pagemeta`add constraint p
  agemeta_pageid_foreign foreign key (`pageId`) references`pages`(`id`)
   on delete cascade on update cascade)`

How should create foreign key on string column? Thanks.